# why sched_setscheduler() does not work if not wrapped within an if block?

Tags: c, scheduled-tasks, real-time

This following code works and requires "root" authentication:

```
struct sched_param param;
param.sched_priority = 99;
if (sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, & param) != 0) {
    perror("sched_setscheduler");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
}
```

However, this one seems working (no error) but has no effect and does not requires "root" authentication:

```
struct sched_param param;
param.sched_priority = 99;
sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, & param);
```

Why ? I compile with gcc / Ubuntu 13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `sched_setscheduler` didn't work in your second example. You just ignored the return value which probably wasn't `0`.

Since you ignored the return value you do not actually know if it worked.

Looking at the man page for `sched_setscheduler` you will find this under RETURN VALUE

```
RETURN VALUE
       On success, sched_setscheduler() returns zero.  
       On success, sched_getscheduler() returns the policy for the process (a nonnegative integer).
       On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
```

If `-1` is returned errno is set and perror prints a human readable string for the error.

Since you said `-1` was returned from the second example `sched_setscheduler` did not actually work.

Comment: Even if I my main() includes only this code, the first example works but the second example does not set the scheduler. I don't understand why the fact of just omitting the if block makes things going wrong.

Comment: Can you check the return value in the second one? what is it?

Comment: In the fist example, there is not any error message, it works well (if I'm "root" of course).

Comment: The second example returns -1.

Comment: Since `sched_setscheduler` returned `-1` the function did not work.

Comment: What's what I don't understand :

Comment: Eureka ! I understand.
The both examples works well when launch in "root" mode.
But when launch in user mode (not "root"), the first one claim for "root" (it displays "Operation not permitted") and then works after switching in "root" mode.
The second one does not display the error message. So, I think it does not work. But it also work at the moment I switch in "root" mode.
Thanks